# How do I properly setup Visual Studio to use already installed Python and Packages

Tags: python, visual-studio, installation, ide

I have added a custom environment:
[image]

and set PYTHONPATH to the site-packages that pip installs its packages:
[image]

Yet... the interactive interpreter does not find my packages already installed:
[image]

Of course it works fine in a terminal:
[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to refer to the tutorial of [*Installing packages and managing Python environments(Python in VS)*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-05-installing-packages?view=vs-2019#install-packages-using-the-python-environments-window) and download and install `pip package manager`(if you didn’t download it, you would not be able to search PyPI and installed packages) in Visual Studio. Then search inside the Search box(`Search PyPI and installed packages`) to download and install the related packages.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tianyu! The problem, I discovered eventually, was Windows maximum path length.